# Scheduled tasks are being queued on windows server 2012

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I have scheduled few tasks in "Scheduled Tasks", but tasks are being queued instead of executing. When I run the tasks manually tasks being executed correctly. I tried all the possible configuration/properties suggested after Google search. Below are screenshots of the task properties.

[image: Settings]

[image: Conditions]

[image: Event History]

Answer (score 5):

This post is a litle bit old, but i had the same issue and a found a funny solution. I don't know if this is your case, but i using a Notebook that was not connected from the power. Well... Just disable the option "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power"
(or just put it on the power) and have fun!

[Task Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CowuR.png)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problems definitely. All trial with other settings failed.

Comment: For testing simply plug the Power Supply and unplug it, while trying to trigger the Task.
With default settings, the triggered Tasks are all queued, when Power Supply is unplugged.
With the settings according your answer, the triggered Task is executed (never queued) regardless of the Power Supply being connected or disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue and after making a small setting change it worked! Screenshot is attached. When I selected red tick option from X option, it did the trick. [image: See the screenshot]

Initially, I selected "Do not start a new instance" and the job was going in "Queued" state. When I changed it to "Stop the existing instance" it worked for me!

Hope it could help.

Comment: This fixed my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to find the reason for this. I had to delete all tasks and add again to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad I only found this post now, we encountered the same issue. 
What solved it for us was to run a sysprep (without generalize), reboot the machine and rejoin it into the domain.

Hope it will help you / someone in the future.